# how to delete old date log entries in Log4Net single file

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, log4net

I am using log4.net in my project. my requirement is to maintain db logger in single file and it should auto delete old entries if file size reaches 10MB. If i set  its completely clear the log file data.

Comment: It is the same as what you want? `clear log` equals `delete old entries`

Comment: to delete old entries on log file

Comment: It's hard to tell from your question, but it sounds like you would have to write a custom appender based on FileAppender. Your requirement seems strange, though, you want to keep a log file until it reaches 10MB then immediately delete it and then start a new one? This seems to me to go against all the principles of logging, i.e. if something is reported as having gone wrong then you _look at the log file_ - but "oh no, the log file reached 10MB so we started a new one and now there's no way of knowing what went wrong"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i found that there is no solution for my question. and i used to create new log after the log file reach mentioned size